# Lookback daily bars only

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I wanted to know how to lookback or pick daily candle values only irrespective of the time frame open on the chart / window.

I need this to calculate and hence display MA on screen (MA displayed on screen today basis close of yesterday) and also to calculate last five days high / low etc.

I can use

```
highestHigh  = ta.highest(high, 5)
highestClose = ta.lowest(low, 5)
```

but here 5 bars will change with TF of chart - 5 minis / 15 mins / 55 mins.  So how to pick daily values?

For the five days high / low I will need  to know to define range too.

Thank you

- EDIT 1

In below code, I want close to be of yesterday even when I am using 5-15 mins today.  How can I do this?  Second question is how do I code a date range? eg If I want to pick highest / lowest from last five days

```
study("", "Daily 20MA", true, scale = scale.none)
MALength = input(20)
barsRight = input(3)
Source=(close)
numberFormat = input("#.##")
plotchar(10e10, "", "")
DMA = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", sma(Source,MALength), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
f_print(_txt) => var _lbl = label(na), label.delete(_lbl), _lbl := label.new(time + (time-time[1]) * barsRight, 10e10, _txt, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, size = size.normal)
if barstate.islast
    f_print(tostring(DMA, numberFormat))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `security()` function for this purpose and pass your highest and lowest variables to it. It would then return the highest and lowest prices of the daily timeframe.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

_highest = ta.highest(5)
_lowest = ta.lowest(5)

[highest_daily, lowest_daily] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [_highest, _lowest])

plot(highest_daily, color=color.green)
plot(lowest_daily, color=color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This helps me elsewhere.  I have edited my question to make it more clear.  I tried to change highest / lowest in your code to close but code wont accept it.  I tried eod too but that wont help either.